# Dynamically changing sstate with useState w/o button click

Tags: reactjs

So i have been bale to use useState and with a button click have been able to change the useState. The issue I am having here now is that I can not seem ot get the state to change within a function,

```
const[duplicateCheck,setDuplicate] = useState ("Unknown");
    function handleLogInChecks(){
        fetch("https://api.apispreadsheets.com/data/RPYeHPoUSzV3TdA6/").then(res=>{
            if (res.status === 200){
                // SUCCESS
                res.json().then(data=>{
                    const yourData = data
                    console.log(yourData);
                    for(var a = 0; a < yourData.data.length - 1;a++){
                        console.log(yourData.data[a].UserName)
                        if(yourData.data[a].Password === password ||
                            yourData.data[a].Email === email ||
                            yourData.data[a].UserName === username)
                            {
                                setDuplicate("Failed")
                                console.log("In loop")
                            }
                    }
                    if(duplicateCheck ==="Unknown"){
                        setDuplicate("Passed")
                        console.log("exited loop")
                    }
                    //This works for setting through the returned data
                    console.log(duplicateCheck)
                    //The above is what works
                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
            }
            else{
                // ERROR
            }
        })
    }
```

I know the useState, the second part of the useState will work on a button click but is not working if just called. Does not change the state.

UPDATED
Here is where the above code is being called. This function is part of an onClick that is called when trying to pass data to a google sheet. All this works fine,

```
    function handleLogIn(){
        fetch("https://api.apispreadsheets.com/data/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({"data": {
                "CC#":"000000",
                "Type":"account",
                "Email":email,
                "Password":password,
                "UserName":username,
                "credits_used":"0",
                "total_credits":"0",
                "credits_current":"0"}}),
        }).then(res =>{
            if (res.status === 201){
                 //SUCCESS
                console.log("Success")
                handleLogInChecks();
            }
            else{
                // ERROR
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: where you call `handleLogInChecks()` ?

Comment: I will update with the section that has the check in it. But this still works when I put in to see if I hit the area where the useState is in it gets there.....I have wondered if it is a scoping issue but I don't think so.